# How does one authenticate with Azure Databricks through .Net?

Tags: c#, azure, databricks

I am trying to figure out how to send HTTP requests to Azure Databricks for my application. Currently I am stuck in authenticating; Every request returns a 401 Unauthorzied error.

I have followed their guide and I created a Personal Access Token and retrieved its secret key. This is my code which would send the request to create a cluster:

```
var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
           { "cluster_name", "hello" },
           { "spark_version", "4.0.x-scala2.11" },
            {"machine","eastus2" },//,
            {"login","token" },
            {"password", "dapi75dcd6e05815ae7bc52cc873b1b0f55c" }
        };

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
        Debug.WriteLine("started");
        var response = client.PostAsync("https://eastus2.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/clusters/get", content).Result;

        var responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        Debug.WriteLine(responseString);
```

But this keeps failing, I suspect that the key names for the username and password is wrong but I have no idea how to figure out what are the correct labels.

Thanks for any help!

Edit: This is whats returned

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 401 </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 401</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /api/2.0/clusters/get. Reason:
<pre>    Unauthorized</pre></p>
<hr />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Azure Databricks Rest API sample](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/api/latest/examples.html#upload-a-big-file-into-dbfs), we could know that we need to request authorization header `Authorization: Basic base64codestring` .

> The token you got from above needs to be turned into a Base64 encoded string. The important thing to note is that you must **ALSO** include a prefix of "**token**:". So the full string to encode is something like "token:dapi56b...........d5"

We could get the body from the [create clusters API](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/api/latest/clusters.html#create)

```
{
  "cluster_name": "my-cluster",
  "spark_version": "4.0.x-scala2.11",
  "node_type_id": "Standard_D3_v2",
  "spark_conf": {
    "spark.speculation": true
  },
  "num_workers": 25
}
```

The following is my test demo code:

```
var url = "https://eastasia.xxxxxxx.net/api/2.0/clusters/create";
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var token = "token:dapi.......";
var body ="{\"cluster_name\": \"my-cluster\",\"spark_version\": \"4.0.x-scala2.11\",\"node_type_id\": \"Standard_D3_v2\",\"spark_conf\": { \"spark.speculation\": true},\"num_workers\": 25}"
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic "+ Base64Encode(token));
HttpContent content = new StringContent(body);
var response = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;
Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
Console.ReadKey();
```

**Test result**

[image]

**Updated:**

Add the Base64Encode function code.

```
private static string Base64Encode(string plainText)
        {
            var plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
        }
```

Comment: That was absolutely fantastic thanks, it worked! By the way, I do want to clarify one thing, Base64Encode is not in the library but is this function right: https://gist.github.com/fringebits/f97a57533113891c460e5d20d7b322a0

Comment: Sorry for missing `Base64Encode` function, I have updated the answer with customized `Base64Encode` function.